# Is it available to patch function of function in python testcase?

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest, testcase

This is an example.

#### main/something.py

```
from example.something import get_utc_time, get_jst_time

print(get_utc_time())
print(get_jst_time())
```

#### example/something.py

```
from django.utils import timezone

def get_utc_time():
    return timezone.now()

def get_jst_time():
    return timezone.now() + timezone.timedelta(hours=9)
```

I want to do like following testcase. But, this is not available.
Does anyone have any ideas?

#### testcase

```
@patch('main.something.example.something.timezone.now')
def test_execute(mock_now):
    ....
```

Do I have to set both functions as patch like:

`@patch('main.something.get_utc_time')` and `@patch('main.something.get_jst_time')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to patch in the namespace of the thing whose behavior you want to change.  In this case you likely need:

```
@patch('example.something.timezone.now')
def test_execute(mock_now):
    mock_now.return_value = 'a mock time'  # probably want to return a time not a string
```

Comment: I tried it. But, it doesn't work well and returned current time.. How can I debug this?

Comment: does timezone use the datetime library? that library is a little trickier to patch in that case

Comment: @naohide, I just tested this with django timezone and the mock worked as expected. As to debugging, I just stepped into the `timezone.now()` call and was in the mock library.  Did you set a `return_value` on the mock?

Comment: @StephenRauch Yes, I set `mock_now.return_value = datetime(2014, 1, 10, tzinfo=pytz.utc)`. I'll try to debug.

Comment: @aws_apprentice I'm using `from django.utils import timezone`.

Comment: @StephenRauch Sorry, this was my fault. I defined function like `def get_utc_time(dt=timezone.now()):`. So, It was executed before.. Thanks a lot.